# Auto-refresh UITableView Help

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ipad

I am trying to refresh a UITableView with new cells every 30 seconds. My array contains 30 elements, and for every new item I add to my array, I want to remove the last cell in my table. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To refresh every 30 seconds, use an NSTimer.

```
NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30
                           target:self selector:@selector(refreshTable)
                         userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Add that new item in your `-refreshTable`. Make sure your dataSource and the table are in sync.

```
-(void)refreshTable {
   ...
   // modify the data source.
   [items removeLastObject];
   [items insertObject:newItem atIndex:0];

   // modify the table.
   [tableView beginUpdates];
   [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:
      [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]]
                    withRowAnimation:withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
   [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:
      [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:29 inSection:0]]
                    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
   [tableView endUpdates];
   ...
}
```

See the [*Table View Programming Guide for iPhone OS*](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW9) on how to perform batch insertion and deletion.

Comment: @Sheehan: Don't assign to a `timer` variable if you're not using it later. But keep that in some ivar if you want to kill the 30-second refresh at some time.

Comment: why do you need to remove last object?